# interview format for internship

Tags: interviewing

I have a last round interview, and all they told me was that it would be a "1 hour interview with a developer." The last round was technical, and the HR rep didn't give much info besides that. I'm trying to prep in the best way possible, so I was wondering if it'd be appropriate to send an email like:

Hi [HR rep],

I hope you had a good weekend! I just have a few questions regarding the hangout with [developer].

What is the format of this interview, and should I have anything specific prepared besides technical knowledge? 
Thanks again.

Best regards,

[me]

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: so I don't have to possibly waste time studying something that might not be in the interview

Comment: there's no point to it, it doesn't do anything positive for you just brings you to the attention of HR as someone who needs their hand held.

Comment: does it make a difference if it's for an internship vs higher end like sr. developer position

Comment: You shouldn't have to cram for an interview, and indicating that you want to do so sends the message that you aren't adequately prepared for the job.

Comment: doesn't everyone study before interviews? I just would rather study more on what the HR rep could possibly reply with

Comment: No, not everyone studies before interviews, and those who do often focus on interviewing skills rather than on skills they should already be well practices in.

Comment: @keshlam Everyone SHOULD study core competencies before an interview, especially if one has been in the industry for a while.  One can use so much routinely that you forget some of the peripheral things, the seldom used things, and the things you've been using so long that you've forgotten the name of them.

Comment: @richardu: study != cram.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @jimm101 on this one.

In the general sense, asking for an agenda / interview discussion points is a good idea.

*However*, in this case you've made it to the last round of interviews.  You've already met with management, and you've already passed the technical reviews.  This final test is nothing more than

> let's put this candidate who claims to be a developer in with one of our developers and see if they get along.

**It's a chemistry test**

You don't study for those.

Relax, be open, and assume you're meeting someone you will work with daily.  With luck, this person may eventually become a very good friend.

Comment: does it make a difference if this position is for an internship? because it is haha

Comment: No, it does not make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the answers saying it is a mistake to ask. I have sat on both sides of hiring panels, and my experience is that if you have an important question, it is usually much better to ask. Far from showing weakness, it shows confidence. Timid interviewees *don't* ask questions (perhaps out of fear of appearing weak?), which means that they sometimes don't know how to answer, may answer the wrong question, or even panic as their minds race and come up dry (I've seen it happen). It stunts the conversation and makes them appear less capable. Or, overconfident people also fail to ask questions, making themselves seem closed off to input and unteachable.

Confident (but not overconfident) interviewees ask clarifying questions because they are comfortable in their own skin, and want to give the best answers possible. It starts a more satisfying conversation, and gives good (usually positive) insight.

In fact, at the end of the interview, when they interviewer asks, "so, do you have any questions for us?," I always say, "yes," even if I don't. If nothing more, I just ask, "aside from what we've already talked about, what else can you tell me about the company / job / team / [whatever]?" And then I listen attentively and say it all sounds great.  It builds a positive connection, makes you stand out, and gives them a chance to talk about something that's important to them. Also, it reveals things about the company you're considering working for.

Your question is a good one. I would ask.

Answer (score 1):

Industries have started to agree that the internship is the new entry-level job, the one you use to get in on the 1-3yrs experience jobs. Entry-level means no reasonable expectation of experience, it's your first job in the domain. They're going to expect, IMO, that you're the person that fits this bill.

Everything held equal, of course having sound technical knowledge gives you an edge if there are many other candidates, as does having a good-fit personality, schedule, etc. etc. etc. That being said, no one is going to penalize you for being eager, for having questions, and for being forward-thinking. If I'd gotten the same email from an industry senior, of course he should already know what to expect from interviews period. But for an internship, the expectation may very well be: this person has never even held a job!

Don't sweat the small stuff, you're interviewing for this internship to *learn* the do's and dont's, and you don't learn if you don't try!

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it.  You would be broadcasting your insecurity. You'll also create work on the other side and sound needy and anxious.

The point of the interview is to either see how well you program, or how good you are with algorithms. It's not a bad idea to study some common algorithms, to exercise your abilities in both those areas.

If the hiring manager or HR person saw your "waste time studying" rationalization, chances are pretty good you'd lose the job.

Comment: I don't agree with this. Asking what to expect for an interview doesn't communicate weakness - it communicates a desire to be prepared. I often ask for meeting agendas in advance of meetings, even if i know the rough topic, is that insecurity? Or a desire to be prepared? It depends on how you ask this but asking what to expect isn't bad at all (though arguably should have been asked when coordinating logistics for the follow up).